# Put like on YT Music song without wakening my phone with Tasker

Tags: tasker, google-assistant, java

I want to make a Tasker script to like the current song in YT MUSIC by holding down volume button for example. The perfect solution is that I can put likes without flashing the screen and silently, so as not to disturb at night.

I'm thinking to use the example of Google Assistant, it can give likes to the current track on command. I read the logs and found an event that looks like the right command:

```
A: Media Operation Type: media.SET_RATING sent to package: com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
```

Next I tried to send Intent of this kind, but nothing worked:

```
Send Intent [ 
Action:android.media.action.SET_RATING 
Cat:Default 
Mime Type: 
Data: 
Extra: 
Package:com.google.android.apps.youtube.music
Class: 
Target:Activity 
]
```

Continued researching and came across a feature on the [developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/interacting-with-assistant#transport_controls):

```
onSetRating(android.support.v4.media.RatingCompat)
```

But I don't know how to use the native functions through Tasker. It may be shell command, Java function or something? Can anyone help?